# Android layout: left item in horizontal LinearLayout forces right justified text to jumble

Tags: android, android-layout

[image: wowrly?]

this is what i have.  i need those bold titles in the group data to wrap, rather than the data on the right.  here's the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
    android:paddingRight="5dip"
    android:paddingBottom="5dip"
    android:paddingTop="5dip">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/igi_product"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:stretchColumns="0">
        <TableRow>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/igi_units"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/igi_uom"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/igi_total"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/igi_price"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

EDIT:

i tried replacing the LinearLayout with a RelativeLayout and this is what came out:

[image: wowrly?]

code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
    android:paddingRight="5dip"
    android:paddingBottom="5dip"
    android:paddingTop="5dip">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/igi_product"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
        <TableRow>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/igi_units"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/igi_uom"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/igi_total"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/igi_price"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the final layout code and image.  the magic was in setting `layout_weight="1"` and `layout_width="0dp"` in the `igi_product` TextView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
    android:paddingRight="5dip"
    android:paddingBottom="5dip"
    android:paddingTop="5dip">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/igi_product"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"/>
    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right">
        <TableRow>
            <!--<TextView
                android:text="Units:"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>-->
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/igi_units"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/igi_uom"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
            <!--<TextView
                android:text="Total:"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>-->
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/igi_total"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
            <!--<TextView
                android:text="Price:"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>-->
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/igi_price"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

VIEWTIFUL:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

for such purposes I strongly recommend `RelativeLayout`.
As I also got a lot of (most tiny) problems with `LinearLayout`,
`RelativeLayout` worked great for me.

Good ressource: http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-relativelayout-example/

Otherwise:
try to use `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` in the jumbled textview, or give it a weight attribute (`android:layout_weight="1"`) or try to use `android:minWidth="50dp"` ...

Maybe one of this could work for you.